# finding cycles in decimal expansion of rational numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, decimal

I need to write a program that prints 0.(03) for input 1 and 33.
(1/33 = 0.03030303.... We use the notation 0.(03) to denote that 03 repeats indefinitely.)

As another example, 
8639/70000 = 0.1234(142857)

I understand, I need to use an algorithm like floyds. But how do I get 0.0.030303030303 instead of 0.03030303030304 in java.

Comment: For arbitary precision you need to use BigDecimal.  For greater precision you should use fractions. You need to evaluate until you get a multiple of 9, 99, 999, 9999 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code, I think you'll find what you're looking for:

```
BigDecimal one = new BigDecimal(1);

BigDecimal thirtyThree = new BigDecimal(33);

//Fix the decimals you want, i.e. 21
MathContext context = new MathContext(21, RoundingMode.DOWN);

BigDecimal result = one.divide(thirtyThree, context);       

System.out.println(result);
```

This yields the next result:
0.0303030303030303030303

Comment: This is implicitly `0.0303030303030303030303000000000000000000000000` ;)

Comment: Of course, you can't store an infinite number, you must choose the right decimals depending on the context you're using

Comment: An alternative is leave everything as a fraction so there is never a loss of precision. The number of digits you need escalates very quickly. 1/97 = 0.(010309278350515463917525773195876288659793814432989690721649484536082474226804123711340206185567)

Answer (score 5):

You can try the following which more robust.

The theory is that all repeating sequences have to be a multiple of

```
1/9 or 0.(1), 
1/99 or 0.(01)
1/999 or 0.(001)
1/9999 or 0.(0001)
etc.
```

So to find how a fraction is a factor of 9, 99, 999, 9999 etc. Once you know which "nines" your denominator is a factor of, you know how it repeats.

```
/*
8639/70000 : 0.1234(142857)
1/1: 1.
1/2: 0.5
1/3: 0.(3)
1/4: 0.25
1/5: 0.2
1/6: 0.1(6)
1/7: 0.(142857)
1/8: 0.125
1/9: 0.(1)
1/10: 0.1
1/11: 0.(09)
1/12: 0.08(3)
1/13: 0.(076923)
1/14: 0.0(714285)
 etc
 */
public static final BigInteger NINE = BigInteger.valueOf(9);

public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println("8639/70000 : " + repeatingFraction(8639, 70000));
    for (int i = 1; ; i++)
        System.out.println("1/" + i + ": " + repeatingFraction(1, i));
}

private static String repeatingFraction(long num, long den) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(num / den);
    sb.append('.');
    num %= den;
    for (int i = 3, lim = (int) Math.sqrt(num); i <= lim; i++) {
        while (num % i == 0 && den % i == 0) {
            num /= i;
            den /= i;
        }
    }

    while (num > 0) {
        while (den % 2 == 0 && num % 2 == 0) {
            num /= 2;
            den /= 2;
        }
        while (den % 5 == 0 && num % 5 == 0) {
            num /= 5;
            den /= 5;
        }
        // simplify.
        BigInteger nine = NINE;
        BigInteger denBI = BigInteger.valueOf(den);
        long lim = den;
        while (lim % 2 == 0) lim /= 2;
        while (lim % 5 == 0) lim /= 5;
        for (int j = 1; j <= lim; j++, nine = nine.multiply(BigInteger.TEN).add(NINE)) {
            if (nine.mod(denBI).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
                BigInteger repeat = BigInteger.valueOf(num).multiply(nine).divide(denBI);
                sb.append('(').append(String.format("%0" + j + "d", repeat)).append(')');
                return sb.toString();
            }
        }
        num *= 10;
        sb.append(num / den);
        num %= den;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: which is the algorithm you used here?

Comment: I made it up. ;) I sure it has a name but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 4):

To properly detect cycles in the decimal expansion, you ought to avoid floating-point math altogether.

Here is a way to do it using integer arithmetic alone: [Algorithm for detecting repeating decimals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315595/algorithm-for-detecting-repeating-decimals)

Answer (score 1):

By using a `BigDecimal` with the `ROUND_DOWN` rounding mode.