# Is there a way to tell if a decimal is terminating or repeating in C#?

Tags: c#, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know the repeating decimal in a fraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946310/how-to-know-the-repeating-decimal-in-a-fraction)

Is there a way to tell if a decimal is terminating or repeating?

Example:
I have fraction: 1/3 and it's repeating decimal - 0.33333333333333333333
I have fraction 1/2 and it's terminating decimal - 0.5

I don't have any idea how i can do it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946310/how-to-know-the-repeating-decimal-in-a-fraction

Comment: what do you mean by "repeating" ? irrational numbers ? any number that can't be acuratly represented by a float ? by a double ?

Comment: Thanks, i search on stackoverflow, but i didn't see that.

Comment: When you say " I have fraction: 1/3", in what form do you 'have' it? As the pair of integers `1` and `3`, or something else?

Comment: There is no built in way to do this but if you are willing to put in some effort you might be able to follow @MichaelAnderson's guide in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098461/how-can-i-detect-if-a-float-has-a-repeating-decimal-expansion-in-c

Answer (score 7):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal), A fraction is terminating if it can be represented in the form of `k/(2^n * 5^m)`, where k, n, and m are integers.

```
#assumes that the fraction is already fully reduced
#e.g. numerator and denominator are coprime
function isTerminating(numerator, denominator):
    while denominator % 2 == 0:
        denominator /= 2
    while denominator % 5 == 0:
        denominator /= 5
    return denominator == 1
```

If you have the fraction in an IEEE float, then it always terminates, as long as it is not NaN or +/- infinity. Finite numbers in floats are represented as `c * b^q`. The terms may be rearranged to be `c / (b^-q)`. b is always 2 or 10, so the number fits the `k/(2^n * 5^m)` format and is therefore a terminating fraction.