# Calculate using int and output float?

Tags: c++

```
//findSlope(twoPoints).exe
//finding the slope of line AB, using coordiantes of point A and B.

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d;
    float answer;

    std::cout << "The X coordiante of A: ";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "\nThe Y coordiante of A: ";
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << "\nThe X coordiante of B: ";
    std::cin >> c;
    std::cout << "\nThe Y coordiante of B: ";
    std::cin >> d;
    std::cout << "\nThe slope of line AB = " << std::endl;

    answer = (b-d)/(a-c); 

    std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);
    std::cout.precision(3);

    std::cout << answer << std::endl; 
    //alternative= std::cout << fixed << setprecision(#) << answer << std::endl;

    std::cout.unsetf(std::ios::fixed);

    return 0;
}
```

I am learning C++ and I tried to code a program that calculate the slope using the coordinates of two points.

I understand that if I use `float` for variables I declared for the coordinates, the result of the calculation would output as `float` with decimals. However, I wonder if I may still use `int` for user input so that I can ensure the inputs are integers.

Extra question: Would it be possible to convert a `float` presented in the form of "#.##" to "# #/#"? More like how we do mathematics IRL.

Comment: You should learn about cast

Comment: You want fractions instead of decimals right?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [implicit conversion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) to double:

```
answer = (b-d)/(a-c*1.0);
```

Or [explicit cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast):

```
answer = (b-d)/(a-(float)c);
```

---

Bonuses:

- for the fraction part: [Converting decimal to fraction c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643695/converting-decimal-to-fraction-c)
- [Why does integer division result in an integer?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/307993/why-does-integer-division-result-in-an-integer)

Comment: `1.0` is a literal of type `double`, not an implicit conversion or cast.   Both of your examples work due to implicit conversions, which occur for different reasons.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `int` for user input, but to precisely calculate anything that contains a division operator `/`, you'll need to cast to floating point types.

It's usually considered a good practice in C++ to use `static_cast` for that (although you still may use c-style `(float)` syntax).

For example:

```
answer = static_cast<float>(b - d) / (a - c);
```

Here, you convert `(b - d)` to `float` and **then** divide it by integer, which results in a `float`.

Note that the following wouldn't work correctly:

```
answer = static_cast<float>((b - d) / (a - c));
```

The reason is that you **first** divide an `int` by another `int` and **then** convert the resulting int to a `float`.

P. S. `float` is **really** inaccurate, so I would advise to use `double` instead of `float` in all cases except where you want to write faster code that does not depend on mathematical accuracy (even though I'm not sure it would be faster on modern processors) or maintain compatibility with an existing library that uses `float` for some of its functions.

Comment: *float is really inaccurate* => ??

Comment: There is no division by integer in your first example.  The result of the expression `a-c` is converted to `float` before doing the division.    And using `double` everywhere is really poor advice.