# Recurring Numbers: How to get a non-rounded recurring number when dividing a number by another number?

Tags: javascript, numbers, decimal

I am trying to solve a particular JavaScript exercise involving recurring numbers and in doing so I need to work with recurring numbers to a good amount of decimal places.

Currently I am using:

```
function divide(numerator, denominator){
    var num = (numerator/parseFloat(denominator);
}
// 7/11 = 0.6363636363636364
// 5/3 = 1.6666666666666667
// 3/8 = 0.375
```

As you can see, the results of the operation that contain recurring digits are returned with the final digit rounded. It is tempting to simply convert to array and pop() the last digit of each number but this leads to problems when we run into numbers that are not recurring such as 3/8 =0.375.

How can I divide two numbers and get a result that such as 5/3 = 1.666666666666666 ? (essentially the last digit is rounded down and never rounded up)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the Big-Number options?  There is a new option in  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt  but also a few 'external' libraries

Comment: I have taken a look at BigInt as an option but couldn't see a solution that would enable me to handle decimals. It's possible there is a way using BigInt but if there is, I do not currently know the methodology.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that was integer-only, but if you search for "alternatives to js bigint" then you should find plenty of libraries, the first I found was   https://bellard.org/quickjs/jsbignum.html  which certainly has bigFloat functionality.

Comment: See this https://floating-point-gui.de/languages/javascript/

Comment: Related: [Algorithm for detecting repeating decimals?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1315595/215552)

Answer (score 0):

For simple cases, I typically use the [round-to](https://www.npmjs.com/package/round-to) npm package:

```
import roundTo from 'round-to';

const num = 5/3; // 1.6666666666666667
// set your desired number of decimal places:
const numDecimalPlaces = (num + "").split(".")[1].length; 
// Based on your question, I think this is what you are trying to achieve:
const roundedDown = roundTo.down(num, numDecimalPlaces - 1); // 1.6666666666666667
// You can also do these:
const rounded = roundTo(num, numDecimalPlaces); // 1.6666666666666667
const roundedUp = roundTo.up(num, numDecimalPlaces); // 1.6666666666666667
```

If you don't want to install their package, you can copy their implementation from Github.  Their source code is pretty easy to follow.